# Python global variable thread not updating

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

Global variable not updating in one thread.

After the serial message is received the API should exit the while loop and respond but global flag stays at 0:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from threading import Thread
import serial
import time
import web
import os

receivedFlag = 0;
last_received = ''
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1", baudrate=9600, timeout=1.0)

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

def receiving(ser):
    global last_received
    global last_toSend
    global receivedFlag
    buffer_string = ''
    while True:
        buffer_string = buffer_string + ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if '\n' in buffer_string:
            lines = buffer_string.split('\n')
            last_received = lines[-2]
            buffer_string = lines[-1]
            print "Serial < "+ last_received
            print "serial thread os.pid: " + str(os.getpid())
            receivedFlag = 1;

class index:
    def GET(self):
        global last_toSend
        global port
        global receivedFlag
        data = web.input()
        print "Recived: " + data.line
        port.write(data.line)
        receivedFlag = 0;

        while receivedFlag == 0:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print "api thread os.pid: " + str(os.getpid()) +" Waiting for " + str(receivedFlag)            
        web.header('Content-Type', 'jsonp')
        print "Responding: " + last_received
        return "localJsonpCallback({\"box\": \"" + last_received + "\"})"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Port open")
    Thread(target=receiving, args=(port,)).start()
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

When I poke it with "t" via the api which should elicit a responce I get:

```
    Port open
http://0.0.0.0:9091/
Recived: t
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Serial < 1100D01H31M08S
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
Waiting for0
.... 
and on and on
```

UPDATE: edited code for os.pid

```
Port open
http://0.0.0.0:9091/
Recived: t
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
serial thread os.pid: 7942
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
api thread os.pid: 7942 Waiting for 0
```

Update: 
tried using queue to communicate across threads no luck

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from threading import Thread
import serial
import time
import web
import os
from Queue import Queue

qb = Queue()
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1.0)

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

def receiving(ser):
    global qb
    buffer_string = ''
    while True:
        buffer_string = buffer_string + ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if '\n' in buffer_string:
            lines = buffer_string.split('\n')
            line = lines[-2]
            qb.put(line)
            buffer_string = lines[-1]
            print "Serial < "+ line

class index:
    def GET(self):
        global port
        global qb
        data = web.input()
        print "Recived: " + data.line
        port.write(data.line)
        got = None
        while got == None:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Waiting" + str(qb.qsize())
        got = qb.get()
        qb.task_done()  
        print "exitloop"
        web.header('Content-Type', 'jsonp')
        print "Responding: " + str(got)
        return "localJsonpCallback({\"box\": \"" + str(got) + "\"})"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Port open")
    t1 = Thread(target=receiving, args=(port,))
    t1.start()
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
    t1.join()
```

output:

```
Port open
http://0.0.0.0:9091/
Recived: t
Waiting0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
Recived: t
Waiting0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
Recived: t
Waiting0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
Recived: t
Waiting0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
Recived: t
Waiting0
Serial < 1100D00H00M00S
Recived: t
```

Comment: What WSGI server are you using to run this?

Comment: I suspect that you are using a server that uses *multiple child processes*, and forking. Chances are the wrong child is reading from the serial port here. Add `os.getpid()` to your prints to verify.

Comment: I'm more concerned by the fact that you are a) using a global variable and b) not making it at least thread-safe. Some sort of locking primitive, surely, makes sense here, right?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: if there is only ever a single thread that can write, no locking is needed. Reading the global is threadsafe. There are other issues, like the suspected mismatch with the WSGI scaling model employed here, though. Better to switch to a proper queue model (like Celery would provide).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're right. I didn't notice there was only one thread being created here. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I have added the os.pid printout to the original post